# Accept your answer to somebody else's question where you opened a bounty

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I recently found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102481/how-can-dhclient-be-made-namespace-aware) that was very relevant to a problem I was facing. Since it had no answer, I opened a bounty. I dug into the problem myself and found the answer.

Since I didn't write the original question, I can't accept my own answer. Is there anything I can do, given that it's me who opened the bounty?

Comment: Since you not going to get your own bounty the only thing left is hope bounty and meta effect will bring you some points (beyond celebration that you found answer)

Comment: Right, but I really don't care about the points...

Comment: But what if the solution you accepted is not worked for the OP. maye because of misconfiguration or something. th OP ave to accept only if it worked for them. the solutions worked for you didn't mean that it will work for the OP. am I right?